# Literature recommendation on extreme asset price movements

Tags: equities, reference-request, exchange

I'm looking for good papers and books covering extreme stock price movements and mathematical theories of stock market crashs.

Comment: A good start is the book by Taleb, "Black Swan". The guy has a fund that literally makes money out of those extreme events.

Comment: @phdstudent: And he made even more money with talking about how ingenious he is... ;-)

Comment: @vonjd I totally agree :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a large literature on extreme value theory (EVT) and a sizable subset that concerns its applications in Finance and economics.

A well known reference in the literature is:
[Modelling extremal events](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540609315)
(Read Taleb's review [here](http://www.blackswanreport.com/blog/2014/01/nassim-n-talebs-review-of-modelling-extremal-events-for-insurance-and-finance-stochastic-modelling-and-applied-probability/))

I would suggest you start there to see if you find what you are looking for.

A good reference for 'pure' EVT is  Resnick's
[Heavy Tail Phenomena](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387242729).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest having a look at the books and papers of [Didier Sonette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didier_Sornette) from ETH Zürich.

A good starting point is the [research page of his institute](http://www.er.ethz.ch/research.html).

Comment: Why the downvote???